# Why do I get a syntax error on line 1?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'm trying to get this to open an url when the icon is selected/clicked, but I get `Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens` on the line `String url =`

```
String url = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.openurl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<application>
    <activity android:name="OpenURL" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I've now got a bit further on this one but when I load the apk file the icon opens the browser with 2 windows - blank and the url. I;m also unable to use the back button to close the browser - it keeps opening the url. How can I correct these issues?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>


package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String url = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Many thanks again!

Comment: Can you post the exact error message ?

Comment: Post the surrounding code to that snippet.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Seriously, try to restart eclipse and/ or 'clean project', else there might be something wrong with the code above that snippet.

Comment: Is that code part of a method?

Comment: you forget . "dot" in android:name="OpenURL" it has to be android:name=".OpenURL"

Comment: Posted all additional code above.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
String url = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
```

can never be the first line of a java file.

You file need a structure like:

```
package a.b.c; // optional

import java.util.List; // optional

public class ClassName { // mandatory

    // your code

} // mandatory
```

If this fixes your error, you should consider reading a Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the permission for internet in your manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

then your main should be like this:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourmainlayout);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(i); 
        }});
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Feliciano,Thanks for this. Ideally I just want to click on an homescreen icon (no button or screen layout) to open the page. Can the above be modified?

Comment: You should try to write something like a widget or a bookmark, but i don't know how to do it.